# OSX Mavericks: reinstall Ruby without reinstalling the whole system

Tags: macos, ruby

I was "wise" enough to uninstall system Ruby on my Mac. So the question is: *how to install Ruby without reinstalling everything?*

*Maybe important:*

1. I can't use AppStore because it wants credit card number, but I haven't got any
2. My friend has the same OSX version, can I copy some folders from his PC and recover Ruby in such way?

Comment: You could always build from the source.

Comment: @ecnepsnai sure. But that will never recreate your `Ruby.framework` folder and nothing will work. So the solution I found is just to ask the user with the same OS X version to copy his `Ruby.framework` folder.

Comment: use Pacifist. http://superuser.com/a/227653/36776